# TypeError: functionName is not a function (Redux - useDispatch)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting `TypeError: functionName is not a function` when I call it with `useDispatch`. The initial `state` return normal as an empty array. This is my code:

Action:

```
export const getTopStories = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {    
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://news-site.com/api');

    dispatch({
      type: GET_TOP_STORIES,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
     console.log(err)
  }
};
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  topStories: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {    
  switch (action.type) {  
    case GET_TOP_STORIES:
      return { ...state, topStories: action.payload};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Page:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const TopStories = () => {
  const stories = useSelector((state) => state.stories);
  const { topStories, getTopStories } = stories;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTopStories());
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to extract an action from the reducer state. If won't work like that. To get the state, you can use the `useSelector` hook like you are doing. But to use the action, you need to import that function and use it in the `dispatch` that you already have.

Something like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getTopStories } from './action.js'; // Adjust the path

const TopStories = () => {
  const stories = useSelector((state) => state.stories);
  const { topStories } = stories;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTopStories());
  }, []);
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to import the function. Thanks a lot for fast reply! :-)